# "Failed to launch kernel" Renderscript error when processing images in real time

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm using [this code](https://github.com/jean80it/RSRTImgProc) to carry out real-time image processing on Android devices. On most devices I've tried (including a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini and an LG G3), it works perfectly. However, on my Nexus 6, it works only 20% of the time, and the rest of the time I get this error:

```
Failed to launch kernel; dimensions of input and output allocations do not match
```

When it does run, it works for a stretch of time before starting to throw the error again. The only other device I've seen this error on is a ZTE Maven, where it throws the error 100% of the times I've tested. Has anyone else seen this?/can anyone explain what's different across devices?

Comment: Can you try adding some logging before calling forEach()? Each of the Allocations there can give you back the Type (from which you can get X, Y, ...). Perhaps one of those Allocations is being altered in between init() and forEach().

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I'm pretty sure I've tried logging everything I can think of (based on [hasSameDims](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/rsAllocation.cpp) which is what I think [triggers the error](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/refs/heads/master/cpu_ref/rsCpuScript.cpp) and no luck, but I'll try it again. What most mystifies me is on the Nexus 6 when it will work for a while, then stop working, despite none of the logged values changing